# What Operations can I use to extract the Hard Edges/Lines from this image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-morphology

I'm able to detect the main hard edges in an image quite well using morphological gradient - see below image. How can I process this image to just extract the hardest/whitest edges? Thresholding either results in a very noisy image or hard edges lacking in detail/too eroded.

[image]

My thresholding result: 
[image]

My goal is something like this: 
[image]

*Note: I'm attempting to use the Morphological Gradient operation as a light weight way to detect the hard/main edges in an image. The OpenCV code will run on a raspberry pi robot so I'm trying to be quite efficient with my resources - thus I'm using Morphological Gradient as opposed to Canny or etc.

Original image:
[image]

Comment: Can you upload the original image?

Comment: have you tried difference of Gaussians?

Comment: @JeruLuke Thanks for your comments, I've added the original image. I haven't tried any gaussian filters. Do you mean gaussian blur the image prior to morph gradient?

Answer (score 0):

I initially said *Difference of Gaussians* but you already had a better threshold image.

So I took the first image as input and performed **Otsu Threshold**. I used the image obtained from the function `cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)` to detect lines.

Lines were detected using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`

My (not so good) result:

[image]

You have the option of drawing the lines onto your original image.